# ASP.NET BackgroundService - Only run sequential

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, background-service

I have a BackgroundService that I start from an API Controller.
There should never be more than one BackgroundService running.
How can I check if a job is already running? So I don't start a new?

**API to start a new job and related code**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> RunJob(JobMessage msg)
{
    if (_queue.Count > 0)
    {
        return StatusCode(429, "DocumentDistributor are running. Try again later");
    }
    await _queue.Queue(msg);
    return Ok("DocumentDistributor will start in about one minute.");
}

public interface IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    Task Queue(JobMessage message);
    Task<JobMessage> Dequeue();
    public int Count { get; }
}


public sealed class QueuedHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public QueuedHostedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
                var calculator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<QueueDocumentDistributor>();
                await calculator.RunService();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Prevent throwing if the Delay is cancelled
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e, "Error in QueuedHostedService");
            }
            
            // check queue every 1 minute
            await Task.Delay(1000 * 60, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}


public class QueueDocumentDistributor
{
    private readonly IBackgroundTaskQueue _queue;
    private readonly ReportService _service;

    public QueueDocumentDistributor(IBackgroundTaskQueue queue, ReportService service)
    {
        _queue = queue;
        _service = service;
    }

    public async Task RunService()
    {
        var message = await _queue.Dequeue();
        if (message == null) return;
        await _service.CreateReports(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the variable `_queue`? If it's injected service, can you show the declaration in the service provider?

Comment: _queue is of type IBackgroundTaskQueue

Comment: Can you show the declaration in the service provider? Generally, it's in **Program.cs** or **Startup.cs**.

Answer (score 2):

`AddHostedService` adds singleton instance of `IHostedService`, so if there is no parallel processing in the implementation framework guarantees the single job execution.

> There should never be more than one BackgroundService running.

There will be only single instance of background service per type running.

> How can I check if a job is already running?

Depends on what do you mean by "job". If `BackgroundService` - then it is started by the framework. If your some custom payload in queue - then you will need to implement some monitoring manually.

> So I don't start a new?

You don't start (usually) background service manually. If `QueueDocumentDistributor.RunService` gurantees single execution of your logic at a time - your are fine.

Based on provided implementation looks like a single queue element is processed at a time.

Read more:

- [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: My organization is using a tool called VisualCron to manage all kinds of scheduled jobs. That's why I don’t have any kind of timer in the service.

Comment: @MartinAndersen thank you for the information, but not sure how this is connected to the code snippet in your post =)